# How to paginate a table that has live search functionality?

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a table with live search function. It displays all data if there is no input, but for UI purposes I need to `paginate()` the table. This is the function that I am using for live search:

```php
function action(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $output = '';
        $query = $request->get('query');
        if ($query != '') {
            $data = DB::table('students')
                ->where('student_id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orderBy('student_id', 'desc')
                ->get();         
        } else {
            $data = DB::table('students')
                ->orderBy('student_id', 'desc')
                ->get();
        }
        $total_row = $data->count();
        if ($total_row > 0) {
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'. --- .'</td>
                        <td>'. --- .'</td>
                    </tr>
                ';
            }
        }
        $data = array(
            'table_data'  => $output,
            'total_data'  => $total_row
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

This piece of code in above `function` displays all data when there is no input in search bar:

```
        else {
            $data = DB::table('students')
                ->orderBy('student_id', 'desc')
                ->get();
        }
```

I tried adding `->paginate()` before and after `orderBy()` and `get()`, but I am getting error. The only way I could use `->paginate()` is without `orderBy()` and `get()`, like this: `$data = DB::table('students')->paginate()`, but I want to use `orderBy()`.
If you know how, please help.

Comment: It's either `->paginate()` or `->get()`, not sure why `->orderBy()` wouldn't work

Comment: What the error you get with `orderBy('student_id','desc')->paginate(10);`?

Comment: I used `->paginate()` and it worked. thanks for pointing that out @brombeer

Answer (score 1):

hi friend please user a **model** to get orderBy and paginate

```
$data = User::orderBy('student_id', 'desc')->paginate(15); //15 default grid size
```

Comment: I bet it would work if I was using a model but I was fetching data directly from database `DB` thank you for your answer